# Computing iterated region integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

A lot of work has been put into region integrals in Mathematica but it is hard to understand from the documentation what is "best practice" in using it. Here is a simple integral that has given me trouble:

$$\int_{x \in B_1(0)}\int_{y \in B_1(0)} h(x,y)$$

where $h(x,y) = 1$ for $|x-y| \leq 1$ and zero otherwise. $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball in the plane.

Here are my attempts. Bizarrely, they give different answers.

```
close[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, EuclideanDistance[x, y] <= 1}, {0, True}}]

NIntegrate[NIntegrate[close[x, y], x \[Element] Disk[]], 
 y \[Element] Disk[]]

NIntegrate[close[x, y], x \[Element] Disk[], y \[Element] Disk[]]
```

`Out[1] := 8.07639`
`Out[2] := 5.78856`

In principle this would be easy to decide with a simple Monte-Carlo code, but my aim is to understand how to use `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` productively.

Comment: `x ∈ Disk[], y ∈ Disk[]` is wrong because a scalar can't be a member of the disk - you want the 2D point `{x,y} ∈ Disk[]`. Also the integrand could be simpler: `NIntegrate[Boole[Abs[x - y] <= 1], {x,y} ∈ Disk[]]` assuming that's what you mean't with the latex $|x-y|$, otheriwse the norm would be $||x-y||_2$

Comment: ... if you _really_ mean the area of a circle, then: `NIntegrate[Boole[x^2+y^2<=1],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]` which is equivalent to `NIntegrate[1,{x,y} ∈ Disk[]]` and just add `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` if you want that. Also compare `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` and `RegionPlot[Abs[x-y] <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` as these are not the same.

Comment: Oh, I see what is confusing: the measure of the integral. Sure, I will change that.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for the `Boole` function that is cleaner than `Piecewise`. I am surprised if Mathematica really cannot get a symbolic answer for `Integrate[Boole[EuclideanDistance[x, y] <= 1], x \[Element] Disk[], 
 y \[Element] Disk[]]` but on my machine it produces nothing.

Comment: There is no need to use `Boole [] ` , Mathematica evaluates `Integrate[1, Element[{x, y}, Disk[]]] (*\[Pi]  *)` without problem.